# Como retornar uma Promise de um AngularFireObject usando @angular/fire no Angular(v6+)

Tags: angular, promises, angular-fire-2

Olá, estou trabalhando em um projeto em Angular onde preciso retornar uma `Promise`em um determinado serviço. Meu código está assim:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {

  readonly baseUrl: string = 'user';

  constructor(
    private afDb: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { }

  object(id: string) {

    return this.afDb
      .object(`${this.baseUrl}/{${id}}`)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .toPromise()
  }

}
```

O problema é que eu não consigo capturar a `Promise` ao usar a função `userService.object` dentro dos componentes. Estou fazendo isso:

```js
@Component({ selector: 'login', templateUrl: './login.html' })
export class Login {

  uid: 'teste'; 

  constructor(
    public userService: UserService
  ) { }

  login() {
    this.userService.object(this.uid)
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

}
```

O que preciso fazer com que meu serviço consiga retornar uma promessa com o objeto que vem do `AngularFireDatabase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar async await no seu service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {

  readonly baseUrl: string = 'user';

  constructor(
    private afDb: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { }

  async object(id: string) {

    return await this.afDb
      .object(`${this.baseUrl}/{${id}}`)
      .snapshotChanges()
      .toPromise()
  }

}
```